# How can i make my rows have border even when my table cells are smaller in size then table headers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using boostrap table.

If i have this table then everything seems ok

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but i make http requests and sometimes my `td` will be smaller then `th` for example
maybe i will have 7 `th` but when i make the http requests i will get only data for my first three
`td`

For example

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">City</th>
      <th scope="col">Zip</th>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in this case my table looks bad.

Please see the image below
https://ibb.co/x5Pj618

This is because as i can see bootstrap has the following css classes

```
.table td, .table th {
    padding: .75rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

this is the reason that when i don't have `td` i don't have border-top.

I want even i have three `td` in my case, this border-top to be applied through the whole table until the end.

For that purpose i don't want to generate empty td - because i have requirement to now show td if there is null value coming from backend for that.

How can i apply border-top for every row even when there are less `td` ?

*i tried*

adding border on my `tr` instead on every `td` but it is without success. I get again border until the last td, not until the whole width of the table

```
.tr {
   border-top:2px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

how can i solve this ?

Comment: You have to add empty td.

Comment: Why you think that there is no other way ?

Comment: If you add border-collapse: collapse; to your table and then add tr  { border-top: 2px solid #dee2e6 } then it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the border from `td` and add a top border to the `tr` without affecting the `thead`, You can apply `.table-borderless` to the `tbody` and `.border-top` to each `tr`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">City</th>
      <th scope="col">Zip</th>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-borderless">
    <tr class="border-top">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border-top">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border-top">
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i copy pasted your code. But it does not see to work. I have also bootstrap 4 cdn included in my html file

Comment: I copy pasted the whole html code.Do i need to include some custom css so your example will work ?

Comment: No, it is working in the code snippet. Are you using any custom css? what exact version of  bs?

Comment: I am using bs version 4

Comment: Ok, in my example the *exact* version is 4.6.0

Answer (score -1):

This is because of you are used the class name to style tr . but there is no such class named 'tr', which is an element. so you should remove the dot(.) symbol in css code.
follow this code

```
  tr {
     border-top:2px solid #dee2e6;
  }
  td,th {
   border: none;
  }
```